# I'm following the tutorial for setting up tf_jobs as given in Kubeflow documentation and I run into error in ks apply stage

Tags: distributed-computing

I'm following this instruction for setting up [TF JOBs](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/tftraining/#what-is-tfjob).
These are instructions that work just fine:

```
CNN_JOB_NAME=mycnnjob
VERSION=v0.4.0
```

This is my init code:

```
ks init ${CNN_JOB_NAME}
cd ${CNN_JOB_NAME}
ks registry add kubeflow-git github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/tree/${VERSION}/kubeflow
ks pkg install kubeflow-git/examples
ks generate tf-job-simple-v1beta1 ${CNN_JOB_NAME} --name=${CNN_JOB_NAME}
```

The command

```
ks apply default -c ${CNN_JOB_NAME}
```

is where I hit a roadblock.
The error I get is:

> ERROR handle object:
>   patching object from cluster: merging object with existing state:
>   tfjobs.kubeflow.org "mycnn" is forbidden:
>   User "student_user" cannot get resource "tfjobs" in API group "kubeflow.org" in the namespace "kubeflow"